# Why is there an extra new line at the end of my Google Docs table of contents?

Tags: google-drive

I am trying to get rid of the extra new line at the end of my table of contents of my Google Doc.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CW9UV5EbbH1JlW_mxZryCiLZ-NCf8vaqh5BE2Xyl1FU/edit

When I delete it, it returns after I refresh the table of contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is just the way the table of contents function is handled on Google Docs.

If you don't like the extra whitespace, just delete any extra carriage returns after the table of contents object. E.g. select some text within the first line after the table of contents, click format -> line spacing and select "remove space before paragraph".

Otherwise, it's just something we have to live with.

Answer (score 0):

On Google Docs:
If you don't like the extra white spaces on the page go on click format>line spacing then click 'remove space before paragraph'
'Format' is on the first line after the table of contents.